# htaccess: Simplify a long Rewriterule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to write my .htaccess file, so I have this part

(ex: http://www.mysite.com/tutorial/php/bydate/p7 )

```
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/(bydate|byuser|byrate|bypost)/(asc|desc)/p([0-9]+)$ $1.php?cat=$2&sort=$3&order=$4&p=$5 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/(bydate|byuser|byrate|bypost)/(asc|desc)/$ $1.php?cat=$2&sort=$3&order=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/(bydate|byuser|byrate|bypost)/p([0-9]+)$ $1.php?cat=$2&sort=$3&p=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/(bydate|byuser|byrate|bypost)/$ $1.php?cat=$2&sort=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/(asc|desc)/p([0-9]+)$ $1.php?cat=$2&order=$3&p=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/(asc|desc)/$ $1.php?cat=$2&order=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/p([0-9]+)$ $1.php?cat=$2&p=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/$ $1.php?cat=$2 [QSA]
```

My questions is:

1- is it better to use that? Or is sufficient

```
RewriteRule ^(album|tutorial)/(.*)/$ $1.php?cat=$2 [QSA]
```

(ex: http://www.mysite/tutorial/php/?sort=bydate&order=desc&p=2)

And I treat the parameters in my php file ?

2- If I want to use the first part, is it any way to simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

It's always the better way to treat parameters in your PHP file. Otherwise you would have an .htaccess-file with a hundred RewriteRules...

Just have a look at the Wordpress .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Everything (except from existing files and directories) is redirected to the index.php file.
This is all.